# Force a 32-bit application to run in 64-bit Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

I have an application that came from overseas, so I cannot just "get the new version" - I've tried.  As soon as I insert the CD, I get the "Not a valid windows 64 bit application" error message.  I'm not too computer savvy, but can follow instructions.  Can you help?

Comment: What application?

Comment: More information is required.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a setup program (usually called "setup.exe" or something similar), right-click on it and choose the "Compatibility" tab of the properties page. Check the box that says "Run this program in compatibility mode for:" and choose "Windows XP Service Pack 3". Then try running the program again.

However, in some cases, the "setup.exe" program isn't actually the one that does the install. Sometimes all that "setup.exe" does is to unpack some files that actully do the install. You may need to dig a bit deeper to discover the actual installer.  [Systernals Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb896645) may allow you to see ehat files are being called during install and allow you to run in comaptability mode.

Knowing the application may get a better answer if someone else has already dealt with this.

Answer (score 0):

From Windows Explorer, navigate to the CD folder. Take a look at autorun.inf with notepad to see what executible it's trying to run. Then right click on that file (most likely setup.exe) and pick "Troubleshoot compatibility".